# Request sent via SoapUI returns no cookie

Tags: cookies, soapui

I have an app which when executed with no cookies performs an ajax call to configuration url which returns JSESSIONID cookie and right after the cookie is set it redirects (302) to login url.

I need to do the same in SoapUI. The problem is that when I call the configuration url there is redirection to the login url and I have no idea how can I retrieve the cookie between calls.

Answer (score 0):

In your testcase turn off *Follow Redirects*; [see instructions](http://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/reference/overview.html). You will subsequently have to perform the redirect in your test as an extra step using property transfer.